# module 'hello_world' not found while running the manage.py runserver in django

Tags: python, django, manage.py

My site is hosted at centos 7, lamp stack, whm/cpanel.

I created a virtual environment `mp_env` and installed **python3.7** and **Django** in `mp_env`.

This **mp_env** is created in the same folder where we have **public_html** folder for main site. In this mp_env folder we have bin and lib. Python3.7 is installed this lib folder and Django was installed in site-packages of this lib.
No. I did not do that intentionally. I just installed python and Django in mp-env. They automatically found places.

Then I created a project **myproject**. I could test it with `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

I could change the database to mysql, create users and login to admin from web browser. It was working fine.The project folder is outsite the **mp_env**.

Then I created an app **hello_word** inside the project directory **myproject** using this example at https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/

I have followed the steps mentioned there and used everything word by word.
Now when I try `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, it gives error - module 'hello_world' could not be found.

Comment: Share also your settings.py. Have you included `hello_world` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes. INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello_world', 
    
]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the project and created a new project inside the virtual environment folder. Then I created the app outside project folder in the virtual environment. It is working now.